# How to lookup big list in hive case statement

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have set of list of products around 100k records , example of list is as follows :

```
'TESTNAME1 *',
'TESTNAME2 * TESTNAME3',
' * TESTNAME3',
'TESTNAME4',
'TESTNAME 5'
```

I need to lookup this values in case statement .

```
CASE WHEN check_prod_list in (lookup in the list as shown above)
         OR check_prod_list2 in (lookup in the list as shown above)
THEN 'PROD_DESC_VALID_1'
```

As the above the list is vast around 100k, I cant keep this as in my hive sql.
Can you please help me with the efficient way to lookup this list as I need to lookup this list multiple times.
I am using hive 1.2

Comment: Why create a product dim table and use it as sub query or join.

Comment: What the data type of check_prod_list  and check_prod_list2 ?  Please provide an example

Comment: @leftjoin It is string data type as shown above

Comment: So, you have two columns containing strings like in your example? It is still not clear. And I believe this is why nobody answered yet

Comment: @leftjoin I have 2 list of product names  and the names are in format as shown above , issue is I want to lookup this product list in my CASE WHEN statement, if the product lookup in either of the 2 list is successful then it is PROD_DESC_VALID_1. So at this point of time currently I don't have any columns for the product list.  I want to implement this is efficient way, So that in future any product names are added or removed , there would  be no code changes on hive SQL side.